# how to make sliding text views

Tags: android

am trying to develop an application where by if a user swipes left or right on the screen, a different text view is seen. This app should not have different layout xml files for the different text views. Any advise on how to go about it or even a code that accomplishes the task is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Go with viewflipper..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a ViewPager. There's a good guide to setting one up (with code examples) here: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: ,thanks for the comment but i already tried out that example but seems like am getting errors, do you have any other link?

Comment: What errors are you getting? That's the best way of implementing it